# How to hide a div individually on click of close button using ngFor in angular 7

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a table whose data is coming from loop. Here when I click 'click here' of status column a div will show, again when I click close button of that div it should hide. Here its working fine but its working like toggle on click of 'click here' but I need to close only when close button should click.Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<table class="table border">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns; let i = index">
        <th>{{ column }}</th>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let row of groups;let i = index">
            <td>{{row.name}}</td>
            <td>{{row.items}}</td>
            <td (click)="hideme[i] = !hideme[i]">{{row.Status.length}}-<span style="border:1px solid;" >Click here</span>
               <div style="border:1px solid;padding:20px;position:absolute;background:#fff;" [hidden]="!hideme[i]"> <span  *ngFor="let item of row.Status;let j = index">
                    {{item.name}}
                    <span *ngIf="j != row.Status.length - 1">,</span></span><span style="position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;cursor:pointer;">close</span></div>
           </td>
            <td>
                <span *ngFor="let item of row.loc;let k = index">
                   {{item.name}}
                   <span *ngIf="k != row.loc.length - 1">,</span>
                </span>     
           </td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component,ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent  {
selectedRow : Number;
 name = 'Angular';
 selectedgroup: any;
 hideme=[];

columns = ["name", "Items","status", "loc"];

  groups=[{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "pencils",
        "items": "red pencil",
        "Status": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "green"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "red"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "yellow"
        }],
        "loc": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "loc 1"
        }, {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "rubbers",
        "items": "big rubber",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "rubbers1",
        "items": "big rubber1",
        "Status": [{

            "name": "green"
        }, {

            "name": "red"
        }],
        "loc": [{

            "name": "loc 2"
        }, {

            "name": "loc 3"
        }]
    }

];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are using only one `(click)` handler for both opening and closing. You have to separate these two actions.

Remove your `(click)` handler on `<td>` and place it on `Click Here` span just for opening.

```
<td>{{row.Status.length}}-<span (click)="hideme[i] = true" style="border:1px solid;" >Click here</span> ... </td>
```

Add another `click()` handler on `close` span just for closing.

```
<span (click)="hideme[i] = false" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;cursor:pointer;">close</span>
```

Live demo on StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvwuqz